# Cleaning up linked list logic

Tags: c, linked-list, code-cleanup

So I've been writing a program that takes any input from the command line up until a '.' character, and then prints out the input but with the lines reversed. So:

> hello
>
> world.

becomes

> world
>
> hello

The problem is supposed to be used to practice linked lists, so I'm using a linked list to store each line of input (string) and then another list to store the lines. So I want to have it so that an incoming character is put at the end of the string list until a '\n' is received and then this line is put at the start of the list of lines. The code I have currently works fine, but it seems to me that the logic is pretty messy. However I can't come up with anything else that works properly.

```
    do {
        string->first = string->last = NULL ; // 'empty' the list
        while ((c = getchar ()) != '.') {
            addToEndOfString (string, c) ; // puts a character at the end of a list of characters
            if (c == '\n') break ;
        }
        addToStartOfList(l, str) ; // puts a pointer to a list of characters at the start of a list of pointers
    } while (c != '.');

    // print the list
```

With this I'm also forced to print '\n' when I print out each line, because they are not stored.

Is there a better (cleaner) way of doing the same thing?

EDIT: addToEndOFString

```
int addToEndOfString ( String *str , char c )
{       
    Character *a = malloc(sizeof(Character)) ;
    a->val = c ;
    a->next = NULL ;

    if (str->first == NULL) {
        str->first = a ;
        str->last = a ;
    } else {
        str->last->next = a ;
        str->last = a ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like the `'\n'` is stored just fine, but you're not putting a `'\0'` terminator at the end. Could you post what `addToEndOfString()` does?

Comment: I dread to ask, but is your string a linked list of characters? Maybe you should post the definition of `Character` you are using, too.

Comment: `addToStartOfList` cause to become the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets

```
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE 1024
char temp[MAX_BUF_SIZE] = "";
do {

     fgets(temp, MAX_BUF_SIZE, stdin);
     addToStartOfList(l, temp) ;

} while(strlen(temp) && (temp[strlen(temp) - 2] != '.'));
```